# How do I mount an encrypted DMG on Windows

Tags: software-recommendation, windows, encryption

I am looking for a piece of software that can mount a DMG file on Windows or encryption software that can mount the encrypted volume as a virtual drive on Windows or mac

Most of the software I have found so far does not mount but as a virtual drive but have an interface to add or remove files and folders from the DMG.

Comment: Ok i think i've found a universal solution.  PGP Portable. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8mPCbZiMkU  But the question is where can I download it.

Comment: Symantec completed acquisition of PGP in June 2010 and PGP Portable began End of Life on February 6, 2012 and End of Availability August 6, 2012. From that time, no additional product licenses will be available for purchase.

Comment: I've edited the title and the question to improve the readability of the question and to put a better emphasis on what you are asking. I've also retracted my answer given that it is not what you needed.

Comment: @Lacer, I noticed on your last edit you added "or mac" and _.dmg_ files are natively mounted under OS X automatically when double-clicked and show in **Finder** under **Devices** or in a **Terminal** under `/Volumes/$name`. So you really do not need a separate piece of software on a Mac as it's already built-in.

Comment: that depends on the software i suppose if it can encrypt the volume on the mac and windows.